# Color array, trying to give them some opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

This is my first question, so here we go.

I have constructed a canvas in HTML and followed a tutorial to create random circles that float around and react to where the mouse is......from here if you're interested.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO6OkltgudE">You Tube Video</a href>
```

Trouble is, i would like to give the colors in the array opacity.

my array:

```
var colorArray = ['#ffffff','#cccccc',....etc];
```

I tried changing the colors to RGB but it did not like this and then everything went black.

Any ideas?

(as I say, first post)

Comment: please share your html,JS code

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I think you're looking for `rgba()`, where the fourth value is the opacity and the first three are just normal `rgb`

Comment: A simple google search of "css RGB color with opacity" returned all the info you need. CSS supports RGBA()

Comment: Here is an example of them in use: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_rgba

Comment: You have to use Red Green Blue Alpha (rgba), not Hex Code (#fff/#ffffff) or just plain old Red Green Blue (rgb).

Answer (score 1):

Try

`var colorArray = ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)', ....etc];`

Where the last number (0.5 and 0.3) is the opacity